# Rest API access a rest resource with authorisation and data transfer in one call

Tags: apex, rest-api

We are integrating salesforce with a third party customer care IVR application.  Once the call is connected I need to get data from salesforce to IVR application.  As this should be as quick as possible using each steps of REST API ie Login steps and dataflow steps are time consuming.  Is there any way I can authenticate and transfer data in a single call?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is pretty clear here:

```
Before making REST API calls, you must authenticate the user using OAuth 2.0.
```

The SFDC REST protocol requires that the `access_token` obtained by the authentication request is passed in as a http header in each REST http request

Why not do the authorization at the beginning of the day when the agent signs into the customer care app, and reuse the `access_token` all day long; taking advantage of the refresh_token flow to handle session time outs due to inactivity?

Comment: Could you provide some sample requests?

Comment: Shebin -- Your question is a bit open-ended.  Have you looked at the SFDC REST doc here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/api_rest.pdf, especially the section entitled `Working with Searches and Queries`  Besides cURL as a way to test your REST calls, I found Salesforce Workbench handy using the REST Explorer utility therein.